# In Java how do you sort one list based on another?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I've seen several other questions similiar to this one but I haven't really been able to find anything that resolves my problem.

My use case is this: user has a list of items initially (listA). They reorder the items and want to persist that order (listB), however, due to restrictions I'm unable persist the order on the backend so I have to sort listA after I retrieve it.

So basically, I have 2 ArrayLists (listA and listB). One with the specific order the lists should be in (listB) and the other has the list of items (listA). I want to sort listA based on listB.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you're unable to persist the order "on the backend"? It would be helpful if you would provide an example of your expected input and output.

Comment: Do your lists have the same elements?

Comment: @Debacle: Please clarify two things: 1) Is there a 1:1 correspondance between listA and listB? 2) Does listA and listB contain references to the same objects, or just objects that are equivalent with equals()?

Comment: I'd rephrase the question, but I have no idea what is actually asked for... Better example data would be quite helpful, too.

Comment: @Debacle What operations are allowed on the backend over listA? I mean swapItems(), removeItem(), addItem(), setItem() ??

Answer (score 122):

Using Java 8:

```
Collections.sort(listToSort, 
    Comparator.comparing(item -> listWithOrder.indexOf(item)));
```

or better:

```
listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(listWithOrder::indexOf));
```

Comment: It's just simpler than the first version

Comment: Does this assume that the lists are of same size?

Comment: No, it's not required

Comment: if lists are not same size then index of missing item in listWithOrder is -1 and because of that order of list after shorting - first missing element then shorted element

Comment: Hi @NavrattanYadav how can have the missing elements after the sorted element?

Answer (score 81):

```
Collections.sort(listB, new Comparator<Item>() {
    public int compare(Item left, Item right) {
        return Integer.compare(listA.indexOf(left), listA.indexOf(right));
    }
});
```

This is quite inefficient, though, and you should probably create a `Map<Item, Integer>` from listA to lookup the positions of the items faster.

Guava has a ready-to-use comparator for doing that: [`Ordering.explicit()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(java.util.List))

Comment: O(n) look up happening roughly O(nlogn) times? That's O(n^2 logn)! You weren't kidding.

Comment: Beware that Integer.compare is only available from java 7. In java 6 or lower, you need to use `Integer.valueOf(listA.indexOf(left)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(listA.indexOf(right)))`

Comment: There's an extra `,` next to the second `Item` argument

Comment: Regarding `Ordering`, here is an example on how it would look: `Collections.sort(listA, Ordering.explicit(listB))`. If your existing order contains only a field of your to-be-sorted objects (e.g. IDs), use `onResultOf`: `Ordering.explicit(ids).onResultOf(item -> item.getId())`.

Answer (score 17):

Let's say you have a `listB` list that defines the order in which you want to sort `listA`.  This is just an example, but it demonstrates an order that is defined by a list, and not the natural order of the datatype:

```
List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
```

Now, let's say that `listA` needs to be sorted according to this ordering.  It's a `List<Item>`, and `Item` has a `public String getWeekday()` method.

Create a `Map<String, Integer>` that maps the values of everything in `listB` to something that can be sorted easily, such as the index, i.e. `"Sunday"` => `0`, ..., `"Saturday"` => `6`.  This will provide a quick and easy lookup.

```
Map<String, Integer> weekdayOrder = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < listB.size(); i++)
{
    String weekday = listB.get(i);
    weekdayOrder.put(weekday, i);
}
```

Then you can create your custom `Comparator<Item>` that uses the `Map` to create an order:

```
public class ItemWeekdayComparator implements Comparator<Item>
{
    private Map<String, Integer> sortOrder;

    public ItemWeekdayComparator(Map<String, Integer> sortOrder)
    {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Item i1, Item i2)
    {
        Integer weekdayPos1 = sortOrder.get(i1.getWeekday());
        if (weekdayPos1 == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad weekday encountered: " +
               i1.getWeekday());
        }
        Integer weekdayPos2 = sortOrder.get(i2.getWeekday());
        if (weekdayPos2 == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad weekday encountered: " +
               i2.getWeekday());
        }
        return weekdayPos1.compareTo(weekdayPos2);
    }
}
```

Then you can sort `listA` using your custom `Comparator`.

```
Collections.sort(listA, new ItemWeekdayComparator(weekdayOrder));
```

Answer (score 13):

Speed improvement on JB Nizet's answer (from the suggestion he made himself). With this method:

- Sorting a 1000 items list 100 times improves speed 10 times on my
  unit tests.
- Sorting a 10000 items list 100 times improves speed 140 times (265 ms for the whole batch instead of 37 seconds) on my
  unit tests.

This method will also work when both lists are not identical:

```
/**
 * Sorts list objectsToOrder based on the order of orderedObjects.
 * 
 * Make sure these objects have good equals() and hashCode() methods or
 * that they reference the same objects.
 */
public static void sortList(List<?> objectsToOrder, List<?> orderedObjects) {

    HashMap<Object, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    int index = 0;
    for (Object object : orderedObjects) {
        indexMap.put(object, index);
        index++;
    }

    Collections.sort(objectsToOrder, new Comparator<Object>() {

        public int compare(Object left, Object right) {

            Integer leftIndex = indexMap.get(left);
            Integer rightIndex = indexMap.get(right);
            if (leftIndex == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (rightIndex == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            return Integer.compare(leftIndex, rightIndex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Also easy extendable for similar problems!

Answer (score 11):

Problem : sorting a list of Pojo on the basis of one of the field's all possible values present in another list.

Take a look at this solution, may be this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> listToSort = new ArrayList<>();
    listToSort.add(new Employee("a", "age11"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("c", "age33"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("b", "age22"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("a", "age111"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("c", "age3"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("b", "age2"));
    listToSort.add(new Employee("a", "age1"));

    List<String> listWithOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    listWithOrder.add("a");
    listWithOrder.add("b");
    listWithOrder.add("c");

    Collections.sort(listToSort, Comparator.comparing(item -> 
    listWithOrder.indexOf(item.getName())));
    System.out.println(listToSort);
  }

}


class Employee {
  String name;
  String age;

  public Employee(String name, String age) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "[name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
  }
}
```

O U T P U T
[[name=a, age=age11], [name=a, age=age111], [name=a, age=age1], [name=b, age=age22], [name=b, age=age2], [name=c, age=age33], [name=c, age=age3]]

Comment: if item.getName() returns null , It will be coming first after sorting. How to make it come last.?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that increases the time complexity by `2n`, but accomplishes what you want. It also doesn't care if the List `R` you want to sort contains Comparable elements so long as the other List `L` you use to sort them by is uniformly Comparable.

```
public class HeavyPair<L extends Comparable<L>, R> implements Comparable<HeavyPair<L, ?>> {
    public final L left;
    public final R right;

    public HeavyPair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public compareTo(HeavyPair<L, ?> o) {
        return this.left.compareTo(o.left);
    }

    public static <L extends Comparable<L>, R> List<R> sort(List<L> weights, List<R> toSort) {
        assert(weights.size() == toSort.size());
        List<R> output = new ArrayList<>(toSort.size());
        List<HeavyPair<L, R>> workHorse = new ArrayList<>(toSort.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < toSort.size(); i++) {
            workHorse.add(new HeavyPair(weights.get(i), toSort.get(i)))
        }
        Collections.sort(workHorse);
        for(int i = 0; i < workHorse.size(); i++) {
            output.add(workHorse.get(i).right);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Excuse any terrible practices I used while writing this code, though. I was in a rush.

Just call `HeavyPair.sort(listB, listA);`

Edit: Fixed this line `return this.left.compareTo(o.left);`. Now it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to sort a list and then make the changes in another list according to the changes exactly made to first array list. This trick will never fails and ensures the mapping between the items in list. The size of both list must be same to use this trick.

```
    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    int j = 0;
    // list of returns of the compare method which will be used to manipulate
    // the another comparator according to the sorting of previous listA
    ArrayList<Integer> sortingMethodReturns = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void addItemstoLists() {
        listA.add("Value of Z");
        listA.add("Value of C");
        listA.add("Value of F");
        listA.add("Value of A");
        listA.add("Value of Y");

        listB.add("this is the value of Z");
        listB.add("this is the value off C");
        listB.add("this is the value off F");
        listB.add("this is the value off A");
        listB.add("this is the value off Y");

        Collections.sort(listA, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int returning = lhs.compareTo(rhs);
                sortingMethodReturns.add(returning);
                return returning;
            }

        });
        // now sort the list B according to the changes made with the order of
        // items in listA
        Collections.sort(listB, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // comparator method will sort the second list also according to
                // the changes made with list a
                int returning = sortingMethodReturns.get(j);
                j++;
                return returning;
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this for java 8:

```
listB.sort((left, right) -> Integer.compare(list.indexOf(left), list.indexOf(right)));
```

or

```
listB.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(item -> list.indexOf(item)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ListComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private final List<String> orderedList;
    private boolean appendFirst;

    public ListComparator(List<String> orderedList, boolean appendFirst) {
        this.orderedList = orderedList;
        this.appendFirst = appendFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (orderedList.contains(o1) && orderedList.contains(o2))
            return orderedList.indexOf(o1) - orderedList.indexOf(o2);
        else if (orderedList.contains(o1))
            return (appendFirst) ? 1 : -1;
        else if (orderedList.contains(o2))
            return (appendFirst) ? -1 : 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can use this generic comparator to sort list based on the the other list.
For example, when appendFirst is false below will be the output.

Ordered list: [a, b]

Un-ordered List: [d, a, b, c, e]

Output: 
[a, b, d, c, e]

Comment: This is a very nice way to sort the list, and to clarify, calling with appendFirst=true will sort the list as [d, c, e, a, b]

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> listA;
Comparator<B> comparator = Comparator.comparing(e -> listA.indexOf(e.getValue()));
//call your comparator inside your list to be sorted
listB.stream().sorted(comparator)..
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is looping through listB and adding the items to a temporary list if listA contains them:

```
List<?> tempList = new ArrayList<?>();
for(Object o : listB) {
    if(listA.contains(o)) {
        tempList.add(o);
    }
}
listA.removeAll(listB);
tempList.addAll(listA);
return tempList;
```

Comment: @boxed__l: It will sort the elements contained in both lists in the same order and add at the end the elements only contained in A. For example if `listA` is `{0, 1, 6, 4, 5}` and `listB` is `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, the method will return `{0, 2, 4, 6, 5}`

Comment: There is a major issue with this answer: You are inserting a reference to the object originally in listB into listA, which is incorrect behavior if the two objects are equals() but do not refer to the same object - the original object in listA is lost and some references in listA are replaced with references in listB, rather than listA being simply reordered.

Comment: The second issue is that if listA and listB do contain references to the same objects (which makes the first issue moot, of course), and they contain the same objects (as the OP implied when he said "reordered"), then this whole thing is the same as `listA.clear(); listA.addAll(listB);`.

Comment: And a third major issue is that by the end of this function you're left with some pretty weird side effects. You return `tempList` which contains a possible mix of objects from listB and listA, and listA has had some objects removed. If you're constructing tempList in the first place it implies you want to do this all without side effects, yet listA is left with many if not all of its objects removed.

Comment: Basically, this answer is nonsense. I see where you are going with it, but you need to rethink what you were going for and edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear what you want, but if this is the situation:
A:[c,b,a]
B:[2,1,0]

And you want to load them both and then produce:
C:[a,b,c]

Then maybe this?

```
List c = new ArrayList(b.size());
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++) {
  c.set(b.get(i),a.get(i));
}
```

that requires an extra copy, but I think to to it in place is a lot less efficient, and all kinds of not clear:

```
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
    int from = b.get(i);
    if(from == i) continue;
    T tmp = a.get(i);
    a.set(i,a.get(from));
    a.set(from,tmp);
    b.set(b.lastIndexOf(i),from); 
}
```

Note I didn't test either, maybe got a sign flipped.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that may work depending on your setting is not storing instances in listB but instead indices from listA. This could be done by wrapping listA inside a custom sorted list like so:

```
public static class SortedDependingList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>{
    private final List<E> dependingList;
    private final List<Integer> indices;

    public SortedDependingList(List<E> dependingList) {
        super();
        this.dependingList = dependingList;
        indices = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        int index = dependingList.indexOf(e);
        if (index != -1) {
            return addSorted(index);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Adds to this list the element of the depending list at the given
     * original index.
     * @param index The index of the element to add.
     * 
     */
    public boolean addByIndex(int index){
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.dependingList.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return addSorted(index);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this list contains the element at the
     * index of the depending list.
     */
    public boolean containsIndex(int index){
        int i = Collections.binarySearch(indices, index);
        return i >= 0;
    }

    private boolean addSorted(int index){
        int insertIndex = Collections.binarySearch(indices, index);
        if (insertIndex < 0){
            insertIndex = -insertIndex-1;
            this.indices.add(insertIndex, index);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return dependingList.get(indices.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return indices.size();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this custom list as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class SomeClass{
        int index;
        public SomeClass(int index) {
            super();
            this.index = index;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ""+index;
        }
    }

    List<SomeClass> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        listA.add(new SomeClass(i));
    }
    SortedDependingList<SomeClass> listB = new SortedDependingList<>(listA);
    Random rand = new Random();

    // add elements by index:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int index = rand.nextInt(listA.size());
        listB.addByIndex(index);
    }

    System.out.println(listB);

    // add elements by identity:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int index = rand.nextInt(listA.size());
        SomeClass o = listA.get(index);
        listB.add(o);
    }
    System.out.println(listB);      
}
```

Of course, this custom list will only be valid as long as the elements in the original list do not change. If changes are possible, you would need to somehow listen for changes to the original list and update the indices inside the custom list.

Note also, that the SortedDependingList does currently not allow to add an element from listA a second time - in this respect it actually works like a set of elements from listA because this is usually what you want in such a setting.

The preferred way to add something to SortedDependingList is by already knowing the index of an element and adding it by calling sortedList.addByIndex(index);

Answer (score 1):

If the two lists are guaranteed to contain the same elements, just in a different order, you can use `List<T> listA = new ArrayList<>(listB)` and this will be `O(n)` time complexity.  Otherwise, I see a lot of answers here using `Collections.sort()`, however there is an alternative method which is guaranteed `O(2n)` runtime, which should theoretically be faster than `sort`'s worst time complexity of `O(nlog(n))`, at the cost of `2n` storage

```
Set<T> validItems = new HashSet<>(listB);
listA.clear();
listB.forEach(item -> {
  if(validItems.contains(item)) {
    listA.add(item);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim Herold wrote, if the object references should be the same, you can just copy listB to listA, either:

```
listA = new ArrayList(listB);
```

Or this if you don't want to change the List that listA refers to:

```
listA.clear();
listA.addAll(listB);
```

If the references are not the same but there is some equivalence relationship between objects in listA and listB, you could sort listA using a custom `Comparator` that finds the object in listB and uses its index in listB as the sort key. The naive implementation that brute force searches listB would not be the best performance-wise, but would be functionally sufficient.

Comment: See JB Nizet's answer for an example of a custom Comparator that does this.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you need to persist something else. May be not the full listB, but *something*. May be just the indexes of the items that the user changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The code below is general purpose for a scenario where listA is a list of `Objects` since you did not indicate a particular type.

```
Object[] orderedArray = new Object[listA.size()];

for(int index = 0; index < listB.size(); index ++){
    int position = listB.get(index); //this may have to be cast as an int
    orderedArray[position] = listA.get(index);
}
//if you receive UnsupportedOperationException when running listA.clear()
//you should replace the line with listA = new List<Object>() 
//using your actual implementation of the List interface
listA.clear(); 
listA.addAll(orderedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem. 
I have a list of ordered keys, and I need to order the objects in a list according to the order of the keys. 
My lists are long enough to make the solutions with time complexity of N^2 unusable. 
My solution:

```
<K, T> List<T> sortByOrder(List<K> orderedKeys, List<T> objectsToOrder, Function<T, K> keyExtractor) {
    AtomicInteger ind = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Map<K, Integer> keyToIndex = orderedKeys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> ind.getAndIncrement(), (oldK, newK) -> oldK));
    SortedMap<Integer, T> indexToObj = new TreeMap<>();
    objectsToOrder.forEach(obj -> indexToObj.put(keyToIndex.get(keyExtractor.apply(obj)), obj));
    return new ArrayList<>(indexToObj.values());
}
```

The time complexity is O(N * Log(N)). 
The solution assumes that all the objects in the list to sort have distinct keys. If not then just replace `SortedMap<Integer, T> indexToObj` by `SortedMap<Integer, List<T>> indexToObjList`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having a very inefficient look up, you should index the items in `listB` and then sort `listA` based on it.

```
Map<Item, Integer> index = IntStream.range(0, listB.size()).boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(listB::get, x -> x));

listA.sort((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(index.get(c1), index.get(c2));
```

Comment: your map should be collected to a LinkedHashMap in order to preserve the order of listB

Answer (score 0):

So for me the requirement was to sort `originalList` with `orderedList`. `originalList` always contains all element from `orderedList`, but not vice versa. No new elements.

```
fun <T> List<T>.sort(orderedList: List<T>): List<T> {
    return if (size == orderedList.size) {
        orderedList
    } else {
        var keepIndexCount = 0
        mapIndexed { index, item ->
            if (orderedList.contains(item)) {
                orderedList[index - keepIndexCount]
            } else {
                keepIndexCount++
                item
            }
    }
}}
```

P.S. my case was that I have list that user can sort by drag and drop, but some items might be filtered out, so we preserve hidden items position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually. Solution based on bubble sort (same length required):

```
public void sortAbasedOnB(String[] listA, double[] listB) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listB.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = listB.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (listB[j] < listB[j - 1]){
                double tempD = listB[j - 1];
                listB[j - 1] = listB[j];
                listB[j] = tempD;
                String tempS = listA[j - 1];
                listA[j - 1] = listA[j];
                listA[j] = tempS;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the object references should be the same, you can initialize listA new.

```
listA = new ArrayList(listB)
```

Comment: Although I am not entirely sure exactly what the OP is asking for, I couldn't help but come to this conclusion as well.

Comment: Its likely the second set is a subset of the first. In which case this answer is somewhat valid, but just needs to be the intersection of sets (remove missing elements)

Answer (score -2):

In Java there are set of classes which can be useful to sort lists or arrays. Most of the following examples will use lists but the same concept can be applied for arrays. A example will show this.

We can use this by creating a list of Integers and sort these using the Collections.sort(). The Collections (Java Doc) class (part of the Java Collection Framework) provides a list of static methods which we can use when working with collections such as list, set and the like. So in a nutshell, we can sort a list by simply calling: java.util.Collections.sort(the list) as shown in the following example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ints.add(4);
    ints.add(3);
    ints.add(7);
    ints.add(5);
    Collections.sort(ints);
    System.out.println(ints);
  }
}
```

The above class creates a list of four integers and, using the collection sort method, sorts this list (in one line of code) without us having to worry about the sorting algorithm.