# Can we make the order of one list based on other?

Tags: java

I have two array lists `list1` and `list2` and I want `list2` order as the order of `list1`. Is there any way to do this? In one list I got the top performing emploee from database and list two got from database second time using the top performing employee ids using `"in"` clause.

---

```
List<Long> list1 = new ArrayList<Long>();
list1.add(5645);
list1.add(2312);
list1.add(7845);
list1.add(1212);
```

and other List of object type:

```
List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
list2.add(new Employee(1212, "A"));
list2.add(new Employee(2312, "V"));
list2.add(new Employee(5645, "D"));
list2.add(new Employee(7845, "T"));
```

where `list1` shows the employee id of top 4;

and I got the employee detail from the data base using id and got this list2.

Now I want to make the order of `list2` as `list1` to show on the html page.

Comment: yes there are ways to do it, have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Long> list1 = new ArrayList<Long>();
list1.add(5645);
list1.add(2312);
list1.add(7845);
list1.add(1212);
```

and other List of object type:

```
List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
list2.add(new Employee(1212, "A"));
list2.add(new Employee(2312, "V"));
list2.add(new Employee(5645, "D"));
list2.add(new Employee(7845, "T"));    

    Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<Long>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Parameter) {
            //Add your logic here for sorting
        }

    });
    // now sort the list B according to the changes made with the order of
    // items in list1
    Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator<Employee>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Parameter) {
          //                your logic for sorting.
        }

    });
```

May be this link help you : [In Java how do you sort one list based on another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate `list1` and for each item find the matching element in `list2`. No need to sort.

```
List<Employee> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Long id : list1) {
    Employee match = CollectionUtils.find(list2, e -> e.id.equals(id));
    // cannot sort, if list2 does not contain the id, or put your rule for this case
    assert match != null; 
    sortedList.add(match);
}
```

This uses Apache Commons Collections's [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html).

Or, for better performance, build a `Map` first:

```
Map<Long, Employee> lookupMap = new HashMap<>(list2.size());
for (Employee e : list2)
    lookupMap.put(e.id, e);

List<Employee> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(list2.size());
for (Long id : list1)
    sortedList.add(lookupMap.get(id));
```

Comment: Yes I did it with the map but I wanted to do this by list only

Comment: Two solutions are here: with and without a map, see the first one.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to let the database order the results:

```
SELECT name, score FROM Employees
  ORDER BY score DESC
  LIMIT 4;
```

If you insist on sorting in Java, use a custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
List<Long> top = Arrays.asList(5645L, 2312L, 7845L, 1212L);
List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee(1212, "A"),
        new Employee(2312, "V"),
        new Employee(5645, "D"),
        new Employee(7845, "T")
);

Comparator<Employee> indexOf = (o1, o2) -> top.indexOf(o1.id) - top.indexOf(o2.id);
Collections.sort(employees, indexOf);
```