# How to use FIELD() function of mysql in JPA

Tags: mysql, function, jpa, criteria

My sql query is something like

`Select * from tableA order by FIELD('ID', 3, 5, 2)`

How do I implement this in `JPA` using **`criteria builder`**?

*EDIT*

```
List<Integer> ordList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ordList.add(3);
ordList.add(5);
ordList.add(2);
public List<Order> getOrderBys(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<?> root) { 
     List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();         
           orders.add(cb.function("FIELD", Integer.class, root.get("id"), ordList));
     return orders; 
}
```

Above is my function which gives list of oders, I want to add only one order same as above sql query. How can I add/call that function in `orders.add()` method? The above method gives error.

Comment: As all JPQL docs for JPA 2.1 will say, you can use "Function('funcName', args)" to invoke SQL functions ... and lose DB independence

Comment: Hi @Akshay, did you solve you problem?

Comment: Nope, we can do as @BillyFrost said but not done for code's sake

Answer (score 0):

We can use with the native query flag.
For example.,

```
@Query(value="select * from table_name where id IN :id ORDER BY FIELD(id,:id)",nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity Name> getByIds(@Param("id") List<Integer> id);
```

Comment: Want to use JPA not native query

Comment: Are you still searching for answer??

Comment: Better if I get answer. As it turned out it is not possible.

Comment: Even I searched and finally adjusted with native query. Better hope someone will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

For that simple case I would not use the `FIELD` function but would sort the result by the sorted list, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866400/5223047).
E.g.:

```
List<Integer> ordList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ordList.add(3);
ordList.add(5);
ordList.add(2);
List<Entity> resultList = query.getResultStream()
    .sort(Comparator.comparing(entity -> ordList.indexOf(entity.getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList();
```