# How do I print a string from a word array, including its duplicates?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have implemented the following code to try and sort an ArrayList based on the arrangement of my variable, wordToGuess, without using the Comparator class. This works for Strings that have no duplicate letters like "hoarse".

However, the problem arises when I change wordToGuess into "stellar". I do realise that the issue stems from indexOutOfBoundExceptionError but I have thought over a whole day and cant seem to find a probable solution.

**My main issue is shifting the whole word "stellar" into my orderedHint ArrayList while keeping both 'l's inside.**

Any help is very appreciated!! If you have a better suggestion on how I can sort an ArrayList without using another Comparator class, I will most definitely learn from it! Looking forward to your answers! :D

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListTest {
    public static List<Character> hints = new ArrayList<Character>();
    public static List<Character>  orderedHint = new ArrayList<Character>();
    public static String wordToGuess = "hoarse";
    public static String word = "";
    public static String fullWord = "";

public static void sortHintsArray() {
    System.out.println("hints: " + hints);
    System.out.println("orderedHint: " + orderedHint);
    for(int i = 0;i<hints.size();i++)
    {

        int index = wordToGuess.indexOf(hints.get(i));
        orderedHint.set(index,hints.get(i));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%d iteration: \n",i+1);
        System.out.println("hints: " + hints);
        System.out.println("orderedHint: " + orderedHint);
    }
    for(int i =0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)
    {
        fullWord += orderedHint.get(i);
    }

}

public static boolean checkCorrect() {

    return fullWord == word;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    hints.add('e');
    hints.add('r');
    hints.add('s');
    hints.add('a');
    hints.add('h');
    hints.add('o');
    orderedHint.add('e');
    orderedHint.add('r');
    orderedHint.add('s');
    orderedHint.add('a');
    orderedHint.add('h');
    orderedHint.add('o');


    sortHintsArray();
    //System.out.println(hints);
    System.out.println(fullWord);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [e, r, s, a, h, o]

1 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [e, r, s, a, h, e]

2 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [e, r, s, r, h, e]

3 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [e, r, s, r, s, e]

4 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [e, r, a, r, s, e]

5 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [h, r, a, r, s, e]

6 iteration: 
hints: [e, r, s, a, h, o]
orderedHint: [h, o, a, r, s, e]
hoarse
```

Comment: Why would you not use `Comparator`?

Comment: Because my assignment wont allow it haha I need to keep all of this within one class.

Comment: *when I change wordToGuess into "stellar"* ... how do you change your corresponding `hints`?

Comment: i hardcoded it by setting wordToGuess into "stellar" and changing up the hints.add in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mostly because of the use of [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) which would always return the first occurrence index, hence *failure for strings which have duplicate characters*.

```
int index = wordToGuess.indexOf(hints.get(i));
```

***Important***: I could confirm this would fail when your `hints` on the other hand does not have repetitive characters. For example this would fail for

```
List<Character> hints = List.of('s','t','e','l','a','r');
```

but not

```
List<Character> hints = List.of('s','t','e','l', 'l', 'a','r');
```

***Soln***: You might either want to keep a track of until what index you've already scanned a letter for and then use [`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)) or maybe think of a better design.

***Note***: Another line of code pinching me is

```
fullWord += orderedHint.get(i);
```

Try avoiding concatenating string within a loop, plan of using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much! Your solution has opened up a new possibility for me to try! May I ask if it is possible to sort an ArrayList based on the arrangement of another ArrayList WITHOUT using the comparator class? I was able to add the whole of wordToGuess, including duplicates, into orderedHint ArrayList. Now i believe I just need to compare my unarranged hints ArrayList and my arranged orderedHint ArrayList! @nullpointer

Comment: @Beelz You need not to have a custom class as such, but you would need some kind of Comparator to sort and that is where you can look for [alternatives in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)

Comment: @Beelz You need not to have a custom class as such, but you would need some kind of Comparator to sort and that is where you can look for [alternatives in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)