# Sort a list of objects based on comparing a field with a list of string

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have List of Student object

And the Student object has

```
public class Student{

    private String name;
    private String town;

    // getters,setters and toString method

}
```

And my  `List<Student>` looks like :

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
list.add(new Student("abc","xtown"));
list.add(new Student("bcd","ytown"));
list.add(new Student("cdf","xtown"));
list.add(new Student("fgh","Atown"));
```

And another list is

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("bcd");
list1.add("cdf");
list1.add("fgh");
list1.add("abc");
```

I need to sort the list based on list1.

My output would be

```
[Student [name=bcd,town=ytown], 
 Student [name=cdf,town=xtown], 
 Student [name=fgh,town=Atown], 
 Student [name=abc,town=xtown]]
```

Comment: The answer to this seems like it could match your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java how do you sort one list based on another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)

Comment: @OndraK. No the link not answer the OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

What about using java 8 like so :

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName,
                               Comparator.comparing(list1::indexOf)));
```

Comment: Is there any way to sort the list without using Comparator and iteration concept

Answer (score 1):

While YCF_L's answer is probably the most elegant, I feel that a simpler to understand solution can be of use for the original poster, here is one

First, create a list of same size as the list you want to sort and initialize all the elements to null:

```
List<Student> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(list.size(), null));
```

Then, go through your Student list and add them at the correct index

With a simple `for` loop:

```
int index;
for(Student student : list) {
    index = list1.indexOf(student.getName());
    sortedList.set(index, student);
}
```

Or using `forEach`:

```
list.forEach(student -> {
    int index = list1.indexOf(student.getName());
    sortedList.set(index, student);
});
```

The corresponding One-liner:

```
list.forEach(s -> sortedList.set(list1.indexOf(s.getName()), s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom comparator.

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = new Comparator<Student>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2)
    {
        int index1 = list1.indexOf(o1.getName());
        int index2 = list1.indexOf(o2.getName());

        return Integer.compare(index1 , index2 );
    }
};
```

and than sort :)

```
java.util.Collections.sort(yourList, comparator);
```

Comment: list1 is a list of String, not of Student, I think you wanted to write `list1.indexOf(o1.getName())` and `list1.indexOf(o2.getName())`