# Java Comparator.comparing not comparing?

Tags: java, sorting

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another) about sorting a list by another list, I tried to do the same thing - but from some reason it doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

```
    List<Double> nums = Arrays.asList(5.0, 0.9, 10.4);
    List<Double> order = Arrays.asList(3.0, 1.0, 2.0);
    nums.sort(Comparator.comparing(order::indexOf));
    System.out.println(nums);

    OUTPUT: [5.0, 0.9, 10.4]
```

It should be [0.9, 10.4, 5.0] (according to `order`). What am I not doing right?

**EDIT:** As most of you noticed, I got answer to the question I linked to all wrong. [Here's what I actually want to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166015/order-list-by-a-related-list-in-java)

Comment: For this to work, each `nums` element must exist in `order`

Comment: Just failed an audit on this... I don't get how the EDIT part is acceptable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are sorting the numbers by their position in the `order` list, but none of the numbers occur in the order list. In this case, [`indexOf` will return `-1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) for everything, meaning everything is equal to everything else. In such a case, the resulting sort order is unspecified - though you may realistically assume that it would not change.

Comment: Oh, so I got it all wrong.. how then do I sort `nums` by `order`?

Comment: @Michael I believe using `order` as the keys for sorting.

Comment: @shakedzy I'd like to add that the comparator does not fulfil the `Comparator` [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). That implies that not only is the sort order unspecified, but sort methods might throw exception. `ArrayList` for example [might throw](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/830ca7b43b95/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java#l288) `AssertionError`.

Comment: Just for fun I played with `ArrayList` and different flawed comparators. I never get an exception with comparators that always return -1, and I never get `AssertionError`s. With comparators that return random integers I often get [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/830ca7b43b95/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java#l781) however. (Of course, all this is unspecified and implementation dependent, so it might vary between JRE:s and releases.)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a list of pairs :

```
[3.0, 5.0]
[1.0, 0.9]
[2.0, 10.4]
```

Then sort this list of pairs by the first value of each array :

```
[1.0, 0.9]
[2.0, 10.4]
[3.0, 5.0]
```

Here is the code :

```
List<Double> nums = Arrays.asList(5.0, 0.9, 10.4);
List<Double> order = Arrays.asList(3.0, 1.0, 2.0);

List<Double[]> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
    pairs.add(new Double[] {order.get(i), nums.get(i)});
}

pairs.sort(Comparator.comparing(pair -> pair[0]));

for (Double[] pair : pairs) {
    System.out.print(pair[1] + " ");
}
```

**Output :**

```
0.9 10.4 5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```java
List<Double> nums = Arrays.asList(5.0, 0.9, 10.4);
List<Double> order = Arrays.asList(3.0, 1.0, 2.0);
Map<Double,Double> numToOrder = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
    numToOrder.put(nums.get(i), order.get(i));
}
nums.sort(Comparator.comparing(num -> numToOrder.get(num)));
System.out.println(nums);
```

**Original (wrong) answer**

(nums is modified in place, and the lambda returning key returns wrong results)

```java
List<Double> nums = Arrays.asList(5.0, 0.9, 10.4);
List<Double> order = Arrays.asList(3.0, 1.0, 2.0);
nums.sort(Comparator.comparing(num -> order.get(nums.indexOf(num))));
System.out.println(nums);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator you are supplying calls `indexOf` for every `num` passed.
The returned values are `-1` on all calls, so the order is preserverd as-is.

You need to sort natural.

Sorting by another list of `Double` should be possible, but unnecessarily complicated, it would be simpler to provide a custom Object which sorts as desired.