# Sorting a List of integers based on a List of strings in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a Data Set something like this:

```
85 [Italy, France]    
95 [Italy]
91 [Israel, Jordan]
85 [France, Italy, Switzerland]
80 [USA]
84 [Mongolia, China]
95 [Antarctica]
84 [African Union]
82 [Argentina]
95 [Tibet, Nepal]
...
```

Which I have sorted based on based on the integers using below code (defining the class model):

```
public class Wonder implements Comparable<Wonder> {
    int hostility;
    List<String> countries;
    //some other data members

    //constructor
    //getters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Wonder other) {
        if(hostility == other.hostility) {
            return 0;
        } else if(hostility < other.hostility) {
            return -1;
        } else if(hostility > other.hostility) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorting Code (PS: [**`getAllData`**](https://filebin.net/f13jkfrr74fv0auc/New_Text_Document__3_.txt?t=7ges19r1) method will return a list of wonders, loading from [**Text file**](https://filebin.net/4j1ykvqn6m9i890z)):

```
List<Wonder> wonders = getAllData(filePath);
wonders.sort((c1,c2)->c1.compareTo(c2));
Collections.reverse(wonders); // ordering highest to lowest
```

After sorting the Data Set (sorted based on integers) looks something like this:

```
95 [Antarctica]
95 [Italy]
95 [Tibet, Nepal]
91 [Israel, Jordan]
85 [France, Italy, Switzerland]
85 [Italy, France]
84 [Mongolia, China]
84 [African Union]
82 [Argentina]
80 [USA]
...
```

**Now**, there is need to sort newly generated Data Set to alphabetically which are the List of countries (strings). For example, in new Data Set there're two records with the same integer 84 (1st integer has country Mongolia and 2nd integer has country African Union), so the second record should come first as African Union is alphabetically before the Mongolia.

```
...
84 [African Union]
84 [Mongolia, China]
...
```

**Question:** How to sort a List of integers based on a List of strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java how do you sort one list based on another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)

Comment: *FYI:* Since `hostility` is an `int`, your `compareTo` method can be shortened to `return Integer.compare(this.hostility, other.hostility)`. --- Sorting of a list of `Comparable` objects in descending order can be written as `wonders.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());`, so no need for `sort()` + `reverse()`.

Comment: Shouldn't you first sort `countries` and then sort by `hostility` and at end by country name. I looked at your text file and for `hostility = 69` there is `69 [Japan]`    and `69 [USA, Canada]`. It will not be same order if you have `69 [Canada, USA]`, for example.

Comment: @Freeman but list is sorted correctly using below answer . If you have an answer then please post it blow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further specialize the compareTo function to enact a secondary comparison. I'm assuming that every list contains at least one country; if such is not the case, you must handle empty lists. The altered compareTo is as so:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Wonder other) {
    if(this == other) {
        return 0;
    } else if(hostility < other.hostility) {
        return -1;
    } else if(hostility > other.hostility) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -countries.get(0).compareTo(other.countries.get(0));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may be looking for this:

```
wonders.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Wonder::getHostility).reversed()
    .thenComparing(wonder -> wonder.getCountries().get(0)));
//don't reverse afterwards!
```

according to @Andrew's style

[A repl.it with the best of all answers](https://repl.it/repls/FloweryBriefComputationallinguistics)

Comment: Did you check that no list is empty?

Comment: List<Wonder> wonders = getAllData(filePath);
System.out.println(wonders.stream().anyMatch(w -> w.countries.size() == 0));
This will tell you if you have any empty country list

Comment: Right! I forgot that you were reversing it. Then, just change the last line to return negative countries.get(0).compareTo(other.countries.get(0));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197404/discussion-between-avi-and-5377037).

Comment: @5377037 it's weird because it was a part of my answer

Comment: @AndrewTobilko re-post your answer. you deleted it.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko When you reversed, you reversed the entire comparator (reversed() after thenComparing()). I reversed only the integer (hostility-based) comparator (reversed() before thenComparing()).

Comment: The first condition check of the `if` shouldn't be present. `hostility` is either greater or lower, and if it's equal, you compare countries (which might be greater, lower or equal)...

Comment: Yes; it should actually be if(this == other) { return 0; }, and I'll edit the answer to reflect this. However, the "best" code is within the repl.it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do, what accepted answer suggested:

```
wonders.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Wonder::getHostility).reversed()
    .thenComparing(wonder -> wonder.getCountries().get(0)));
```

on text file, that you provided, you will get next result:

```
95 [Antarctica]
95 [Italy]
95 [Tibet, Nepal]
91 [Israel, Jordan]
85 [France, Italy, Switzerland]
85 [Italy, France]
84 [African Union] 
84 [Mongolia, China]
82 [Argentina]
80 [USA]
70 [Australia]
69 [Japan]
69 [USA, Canada]
65 [The Hawaiian Islands]
65 [USA]
55 [Russia]
50 [Brazil, Argentina]
19 [Tanzania]
17 [Northern Ireland]
16 [China]
12 [African Union]
10 [Australia]
10 [Brazil]
2 [USA]
```

But, if you first sort `countries` and then do accepted answer:

```
wonders.forEach(wonder -> Collections.sort(wonder.getCountries()));
wonders.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Wonder::getHostility).reversed().
    thenComparing(wonder -> wonder.getCountries().get(0)));
```

then you will get:

```
95 [Antarctica]
95 [Italy]
95 [Nepal, Tibet]
91 [Israel, Jordan]
85 [France, Italy] 
85 [France, Italy, Switzerland]
84 [African Union]
84 [China, Mongolia]
82 [Argentina]
80 [USA]
70 [Australia]
69 [Canada, USA]
69 [Japan]
65 [The Hawaiian Islands]
65 [USA]
55 [Russia]
50 [Argentina, Brazil]
19 [Tanzania]
17 [Northern Ireland]
16 [China]
12 [African Union]
10 [Australia]
10 [Brazil]
2 [USA]
```

Pay attention on `hostility` with values `85` and `69` in these two list. The order is not the same. Don't know if this is relevant to you.

P.S. If you implemente `Comparable#compareTo()`, you should also implement `equals()` because there is contract between them:

```
(x.compareTo(y) == 0) == (x.equals(y))
```

If this is not the case you should make note: `This class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals.`

Last thing:

`compareTo()` must throw `NullPointerException` if current object get compared to `null` object as opposed to `equals()` which return `false` on such scenario.

Comment: I see in my case, sorting the countries first is not a solution. BTW, thanks for your answer. up voted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what is your issue. Does below pseudo code solve your problem ?

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Wonder other) {
    if(hostility == other.hostility) {
       // let's compare the strings list when hostility integer are equals (84, 84)
       String firstOtherCountry = other.countries.SortAlphabetically().get(0);           
       // we sort the countries list for current line and other wonder
       // you compare alphabetically first element of each list : 
       // return 1, 0 or -1 here.
    } else if(hostility < other.hostility) {
        return -1;
    } else if(hostility > other.hostility) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[How can I sort a List alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically)

Comment: doesn't understand this `.SortAlphabetically()` ?

Comment: The key point of your question is that you want to sort by hostility and then by alphabetical order of countries