# How to sort values in customized order

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, arraylist

Guys I have final String of values which I am matching with values from DB. After matching I want string to appear in particular order, how can I customize this sort process or is there any other ways to achieve  this. For more info please look into code below. Appreciated for help.

```html
public static final String FRUITS ="Mango|Banana|Pear|Orange"; //want to maintain this order

List<String> retriveFruits= getFruitsDAO.fruitsList(); //this gets fruits from DB
List<String> afterSortList= new ArrayList<String>();

for(String names: retriveFruits){

    if(names.getKeyValue().matches(FRUITS)){
      afterSortList.add(names.getKeyValue());
    }
}
```

so after sorting names should maintian the order of Fruits ="Mango,Banana,Pear,Orange"; how do I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the regular expression with a List of fruits, you can do it as follows

```
public static final List<String> FRUITS = Arrays.asList("Mango", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange");

List<String> retriveFruits= getFruitsDAO.fruitsList();
List<String> afterSortList= new ArrayList<String>();

for(String names: retriveFruits){

    if(fruits.contains(names.getKeyValue())){
      afterSortList.add(names.getKeyValue());
    }
}

afterSortList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(FRUITS::indexOf));
```

From [How to sort a List based on another List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another)

The comparator transforms the elements to List indexes and essentially performs a sort of numbers `0, 1, 2, 3`. As we know `Comparator.compare(a, b)` needs to return `0` for equal elements, negative if `a < b` and positive if `a > b`, therefore:

```
"Pear" "Pear"    -> compare(2, 2) = 0
"Banana" "Mango" -> compare(1, 0) = 1
"Pear" "Orange"  -> compare(2, 3) = -1
```

---

As can be seen from xerx593's answer, it's possible to use different kinds of collections to fulfill the algorithm, for example `TreeSet` to perform the sorting while adding, if duplicates aren't required, and a `Map<String, Integer>` to perform the lookup of the index which is done with `List.indexOf()` here.

The (theoretical) performance characteristics are discussed in the linked question, but this is the shorthand version. If performance is an **actual** measured concern, the filtering and sorting *needs* to be done in the database, which is designed exactly for the purpose of filtering and sorting (among other things).

Comment: This worked for me as well. Appreciated for great effort.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `"Mango|Banana|Pear|Orange"` fixed, I would go about it "like that":

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sortIndiv());
    }
    // choose "richer" datastructure: fruit name as key, sort order as value:
    public static final Map<String, Integer> VALID_FRUITS = Map.of(
      "Mango", 0, 
      "Banana", 1,
      "Pear", 2,
      "Orange", 3);//want to maintain this order
    // Map.of(k,v,k,v,...) -> java >= 9

    // a "more generalized" result type: Collection<String>
    public static Collection<String> sortIndiv() {
        List<String> retriveFruits = Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{"Pear",
                    "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Papaya"}
        ); // fix values for test purpose, otherwise ... dao.fruitList ...

        //here "the magic"...
        //A (self-sorting) TreeSet with a custom comparator
        //..using VALID_FRUITS:
        Collection<String> result = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return VALID_FRUITS.get(o1).compareTo(VALID_FRUITS.get(o2)); // == FRUITS.get(o1) - FRUITS.get(o2);
            }
        });

        // iterate: O(n)
        for (String fruit : retriveFruits) {
            // filter valids:
            if (VALID_FRUITS.containsKey(fruit)) {
                // add to result O(log(n))!
                result.add(fruit);
            }
            //so after sorting names should maintian the order final String Fruits ="Mango|Banana|Pear|Orange"; how do I achieve this
        }
        //done!
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Mango, Banana, Pear, Orange]
```

---

If `Collection` is not an acceptable return/result type (esp. when result contains/should contain **duplicates**, the **TreeSet** approach is **not acceptable**), then `ArrayList` and `sort()` can do the job comparably efficient (and **allow duplicates**):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> retriveFruits = Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{"Pear",
                    "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Papaya", "Mango", "Mango"}
        ); // dao.fruitList ...
        System.out.println(sortIndivSortedSet(retriveFruits));
        System.out.println(sortIndivQuickSort(retriveFruits));
    }
    public static final Map<String, Integer> VALID_FRUITS = Map.of("Mango", 0, "Banana", 1, "Pear", 2, "Orange", 3);
    //want to maintain this order

    private static Comparator<String> customComparator() {
        return new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return VALID_FRUITS.get(o1).compareTo(VALID_FRUITS.get(o2)); // == FRUITS.get(o1) - FRUITS.get(o2);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Collection<String> sortIndivSortedSet(List<String> retriveFruits) {
        Collection<String> result = new TreeSet<>(customComparator());
        for (String fruit : retriveFruits) {
            if (VALID_FRUITS.containsKey(fruit)) {
                result.add(fruit);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<String> sortIndivQuickSort(List<String> retriveFruits) {
       List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(retriveFruits.size());

       // O(n) 
        for (String fruit : retriveFruits) {
            if (VALID_FRUITS.containsKey(fruit)) {
                // x
                // O(1)
                result.add(fruit);
            }
        }
        // +
        // O(n log(n))
        result.sort(customComparator());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
[Mango, Banana, Pear, Orange]
[Mango, Mango, Mango, Banana, Pear, Orange]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help @xerx593. This is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome & thank you! :) From there (of course) you have many options, esp. the data structure of `VALID_FRUITS` ...there are many "structures", which can store a "string and an index" (...String[], List<String>, Enum, ...) ...but(!): Map<String, Integer> is (one of) the quickest regarding `containsKey`;)

Comment: ...even more significant: `Map.get(key)` is *way faster than* `List.indexOf(key)`;p

Comment: While it is true that `Map.get()` is faster than `List.indexOf()` (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)`), in a case like this it isn't significant. The `n` will never be large enough to matter speed-wise, because if it gets large enough a completely different solution should be sought (such as filtering and ordering the results directly in the database). But this is a good example showing how different collections can be used, as the crux of the algorithm is `Comparator` and a collection that can hold some kind of index (whether it's a list index or a `Map<String, Integer>`).

Comment: ..I agree/assumed the same regarding `VALID_FRUITS` (`"n"` is small), but what about the `"m"`? (the size of input list)

Comment: We're still talking about *fruits* here. Since the output will be a list (or set) of ordered fruit names, it's micro-optimization. You would not write this kind of code in production anyway, but do it in the database where it would far outperform any Java solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some simple method:
First you just need a comparator where you define your order:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class DefinedComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    List<String> definedOrder = // define your custom order
            Arrays.asList("Mango", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange");

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(s1)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(s2)));

    }
}
```

And let's say you have a list:

```
List<String> afterSortLIst= new ArrayList<String>();
        afterSortLIst.add("Orange");
        afterSortLIst.add("Mango");
        afterSortLIst.add("Banana");
        afterSortLIst.add("Pear");
```

And the list with comparator:

```
Collections.sort(afterSortLIst, new DefinedComparator());
```

The output will be:

```
[Mango, Banana, Pear, Orange]
```

Comment: I am glad to help you :).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use sort() function in java.
first import:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

and then simply DO:

```
Arrays.sort(afterSortLIst);
```