# how to sort arrayList based on another arrayList in android

Tags: java, android

I checked many samples but I couldn't figure out how could I implement Comparator or another method with my problem . I try to explain my problem clearly .
I have an arrayList as follow :
my Datamodel include an int as id and a String as name for each object ;

```
arrayList 1 = {id=0 - value= "name0", id=1 - value= "name1" , id = 2 - value = "name2"};
```

my second Arraylist also include an datamodel with more items but it include also the value of fisrt arrayList as follow  :

```
arrayList 2 = {id = 100 - age = 20 - value ="name2",id = 101 - age = 21 - value ="name0",id = 102 - age = 18 - value ="name1"};
```

now I want to sort the second arrayList based on firstArrayList(value order) as follow :

```
orderedArrayList = {id = 101 - age = 21 - value ="name0",id = 102 - age = 18 - value ="name1",id = 100 - age = 20 - value ="name2"}
```

how Can achieve that?Can somebody help me to do this ? My android api is 21 also .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code showing your attempt..

Comment: What is the relationship between these three lists?

Comment: In java8, you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you were trying to sort the second arrayList based on the firstArrayList. From what I am seeing in your code, you are trying to sort a list of tuples.  A tuple is a list of element but it can be consider 1 element in a list. I recommend reinitialize both of your arrays as a list of tuple like this

//a list of tuples of 2 elements
arrayList 1 = { [id=0 - value= "name0"], [id=1 - value= "name1"] , [id = 2 - value = "name2"]};

//a list of tuples of 3 elements
arrayList 2 = { [id = 100 - age = 20 - value ="name2"], [id = 101 - age = 21 - value ="name0"], [id = 102 - age = 18 - value ="name1"]};

The code above is not the right syntax, I am just using pseudocode. Also, if you want to sort elements within the list, I suggest import this java library

import java.util.Arrays;

From there you can use arrayList.sort() (again not the right syntax). Let me know if that help!